# Jasper Report not getting the correct path

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a report in jasper and want to use a logo (gif) that is inside my application (inside /src/main/resources/img)

The Code used to rettrieve the image logo is

```
public void imprimir(MyReport myreport) throws Exception    
{

    List myReportList = new ArrayList();

    File logo = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("img/myLogo.gif").getPath());
    myreport.setLogo(logo);
    myReportList.add(myreport);

    FileInputStream fis = (FileInputStream) getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("jasper/myreport.jasper");
    // JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(fis);
    JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(fis, null, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(myReportList));
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, "c:/myreport.pdf");

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print, baos);

    DataSource datasource =  new ByteArrayDataSource(baos.toByteArray(), "application/pdf");

    Email mail = new Email();

    mail.setFromLabel("xxxxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.yyy.zz");
    mail.setTo("destiny@xxxxxxxx.yyy.zz");
    mail.setSubject("myreport");
    mail.setMessage("Mesage");

    EmailService emailService = new EmailService();
    emailService.sendEmail(mail, datasource);

}
```

But this path does not exists.

```
[Server:server01] 09:40:12,492 ERROR [stderr] (default task-3) Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Java\AS\wildfly-8.1.0.Final\content\MyProject.war\WEB-INF\classes\img\logo.gif
```

So, as it seems, the Path is beeing resolved to a different value.
The deployment is made over a Wildfly 8.1 Final in domain mode (Clustered).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Your `myLogo.gif` has been package in `MyProject.war` file. The path `C:\Java\AS\wildfly-8.1.0.Final\content\MyProject.war\WEB-INF\classes\img\logo.gif` isn't exist.

I suggest two solution to resolve this issue.

1.Move `myLogo.gif` out of `MyProject.war`. Use real path to load your gif file.

```
File logo = new File(realPath);
myreport.setLogo(logo);
```

2.Change the `myreport.setLogo(logo)` method's parameter type to `InputStream`.

```
InputStream logoInputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("img/myLogo.gif");
myreport.setLogoInputStream(logoInputStream);
```

Comment: I made it with a different approach.  I was able to read the logo as a resource stream and then created a temp file and used it.